# Generating Apache AXIS2 WebServices from a (my)SQL schema?

Tags: java, web-services, code-generation, apache-axis

Is there any tool that could be used to generate some code for apache Axis2 from a (my)sql schema.  For example, the following schema:

```
desc name;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| name  | longtext         | NO   | MUL |         |       |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

would generate... :

```
interface Name
 {
 public long getId();
 public String getName();
 }

interface MyService
{
public Name getNameById(long id);
public List<Name> getNamesByName(String name);
}
```

with implementation, wsdl etc....

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a tool that I am in the process of open sourcing which *may* meet your needs. Please drop me a line at tshivaraj gmail.